# Multisite wp-admin goes to blank screen after forwarding URL

Tags: multisite

i have wordpress multisite setup on my LAMP here at home (static ip address)
Using my ip in any browser it seems to work flawlessly (i have four subdirectory network sites running on it)
This evening i went over to one of my domain registrars and forwarded the domain name to my static ip address (clone method).

unfortunately, if i navigate to my wordpress site using the URL/wp-admin, i cannot access the dashboard on any of the network sites (it just shows a blank screen in the browser). The various networked sites front ends appear to be working normally although the login meta doesnt work (its does absolutely nothing...as if there's no hyperlink)

So essentially, static ip address method of getting to multisite works fine...
URL forwarding = no login to dashboard using meta or wp-admin... but everything appears to work on the front end

any ideas?

Comment: If you haven't yet [enabled debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress), you should do so -- if the blank page is due to a PHP fatal error, having debugging turned on will let you see what the error is.

Comment: you are not going to believe this (perhaps thats not true)...i woke up this morning, after i believe not having done anything on the site during my sleep, and the dashboard is working. It has to be the "A" records changes i made prior to going to bed last nite. I am desperatly wanting to delete them and go back to the http 301 redirect to see what happens ...but i think ill let sleeping dogs lie now!!! I am going to shut down the clone server and boot back up the multisite one i was using originally to see what happens. Hopefully, this will be problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue on each multi-site I've installed.

When you set up the multisite network for WordPress you were asked to copy some code into the .htaccess file.

Change the following line:

`RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]`

to:

`RewriteRule (wp-(login|content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]`

The first line will ONLY work on the main site url. The second line adds wp-login to the list of acceptable wp folders/files and loads them relative to the root. The problem with this is rule is that it does not matter where these components appear in the url - you can write a blog post with the url `'/how-to-use-wp-admin/'` and the website will internally attempt to redirect you to `'/wp-admin/'`. What are the chances of that, though?